# how to send an sms using vs2003

Tags: c#

im doing a application through which i want to send an sms.im having a gsm enabled modem.can anyone give me an idea or please send me some links to lookup on it.

we dont have sql, not using asp.net.we need to do it in c#

Answer (score 2):

These two articles are result of a quick google search. Hope this helps

[How to send SMS messages from C# using an SQL database](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMS_message_from_SQL.aspx)

[Sending SMS using .NET through a Web service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/SendSmsThroughWS.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[How To Send and Receive SMS using GSM Modem](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx) might be a good start.
More info here: [google](http://www.google.se/search?q=c%23+send+sms+gsm+modem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:sv-SE:official&client=firefox-a)